# phonegap popup window open and close after callback from PHP

Tags: php, cordova, popup, window, window.open

I am attempting to login using a SAML redirect from my app for a login.

This is what I want to do:
1)launch app, on deviceready open a new window and they will be redirected to a login screen (php page)
2)After successful login on the idp server, the window closes and the app is ready for use.  OR they are redirected back to the app's landing page (I'm pretty sure this is not possible because you can't view the local file system to point to).

I can't seem to find an elegant way without the user having to close the window themselves.
Since the window is redirected from the idp server, it cannot close itself, because it did not open it...the app did.

Am I over thinking this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check ChildBrowser plugin for Phonegap [here](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser). Maybe it is what you are looking for.

Comment: Link-only answers are better-suited as a comment.